# How to convert readily given grouped data into bins using R?

Tags: r, statistics, binning

The following table gives the frequency distribution of the number of credit cards possessed by 80 adults.

```
No.Credit Cards  No.of Adults
 0 to 3               18
 4 to 7               26
 8 to 11              22
 12 to 15             11
 16 to 19              3
```

So basically I was given the grouped data above and was asked to create an ogive using R and by using the ogive, I need to find the percentage of adults who possess 10 or fewer credit cards using R as well. I did some research and apparently I need to use data binning and convert the table into data frame or something before I can do any of that. The thing is, all of the tutorials that I found was teaching me how to bin a set of scattered and unstructured data and group them into ranges, but not how to replicate readily given data like the one in the table above. What should I do in this case ? I am completely new to all these so please go easy on me. Thanks.

Comment: `cumsum(x$No.of.Adults)/sum(x$No.of.Adults)`? You can't answer (accurately) the exact question of *"10 or fewer cards"*, since your data does not include 10 in the binning conditions, but you can easily answer *"11 or fewer cards"*.

Comment: If you intend to interpolate so that you can answer the question of *"10 or fewer cards"*, then it appears you are doing a distribution-fitting operation. Is that what you're trying to do? That's a big topic (distribution fitting) unless you have prior knowledge of what you expect or if you have distributions against which you want to compare this (in which case, `chisq.test` and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) are your friends).

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide the distribution for the data generating process.
For count data, an obvious choice is Poisson, but there are others and you could check the literature for credit card possession to see if Poisson is a reasonable choice.

First, let's create your sample data.

```
> library(dlyr)

> data <- data.frame(x=factor(
   c(rep(1, 18),
     rep(2, 26),
     rep(3, 22),
     rep(4, 11),
     rep(5, 3)),
   labels=c('0-3', '4-7', '8-11', '12-15', '16-19')))
 
> count(data, x)
      x  n
1   0-3 18
2   4-7 26
3  8-11 22
4 12-15 11
5 16-19  3
```

We will use the `fitdistcens` function from the **fitdistrplus** package to fit a Poisson distribution to the binned counts. This function needs a data frame with two columns as input. The columns are the left and right "bins" that categorise the discrete data.

```
> censdata <- transmute(data, 
                   left=case_when(x=='0-3'~0,
                                  x=='4-7'~4,
                                  x=='8-11'~8,
                                  x=='12-15'~12,
                                  x=='16-19'~16),
                   right=case_when(x=='0-3'~3,
                                   x=='4-7'~7,
                                   x=='8-11'~11,
                                   x=='12-15'~15,
                                   x=='16-19'~19))
```

Now we fit the Poisson distribution to this "censored" data.

```
> library(fitdistrplus)
> fit.pois <- fitdistcens(censdata, 'pois')
> fit.pois
Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' on censored data by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
       estimate
lambda 7.801006
```

We can now simulate the actual data based on this information.

```
> set.seed(123)
> n <- nrow(censdata)
> sim_pois <- rpois(n, lambda=fit.pois$estimate)
```

Check how close our simulated data matches the sample.

```
> table(cut(sim_pois, br=c(0,3,7,11,15,Inf), right=TRUE, include=TRUE))

   [0,3]    (3,7]   (7,11]  (11,15] (15,Inf] 
       5       37       32        5        1
```

Not great, but that's only 1 simulation, and perhaps another distribution may fit better, but let's continue with your objective: to determine the percentage of adults who possess 10 or fewer credit cards.

```
> sum(sim_pois<=10)/length(sim_pois)
[1] 0.85
```

So that's 85% according to one simulation. Let's do this 1000 times to get a more accurate result and some estimate of the uncertainty. Create a function to do the simulation as above.

```
sim_pois <- function(data) {
  fit.pois <- fitdistcens(data, 'pois')
  rpois(nrow(data), lambda=fit.pois$estimate)
}
```

And call it 1000 times, saving the result.

```
> sims_pois <- replicate(1000, sim_pois(data=censdata))
```

The result is a matrix with 80 rows (your sample) and 1000 columns (the simulations). The proportion of each column that has 10 or fewer is given by:

```
> p.10 <- colSums(sims_pois <= 10) / nrow(censdata)
```

And the mean of all of these is your estimate.

```
> est <- mean(p.10); est
[1] 0.834575
```

A 95% credible interval is given by:

```
> quantile(p.10, probs=c(0.05, 0.95))
    5%    95% 
0.7625 0.9000
```

So, if credit card possession was Poisson distributed, the percentage of adults who possess 10 or fewer credit cards is estimated to be 83.5% (76.3% - 90.0%).